# Memory usage comparison Xamarin.Android vs Sencha

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

So I have got a Xamarin.Android application and a Sencha application.
Both are exactly the same application just developed on two different frameworks.

Now the Sencha application consumes around 60mb - 100mb RAM and the Xamarin app, on the other hand, takes 100mb - 250mb of RAM.
I understand that due to Mono.Android runtime the Xamarin App is supposed to take much memory, so I created a blank app on Xamarin.Android and it takes approx 90mb - 100mb memory.

So my question is how can I reduce the memory usage by the Xamarin app? Or is it normal to have this kind of RAM usage on a Xamarin Application?

Is there any reference point which I can consider in order to benchmark my application's RAM usage?

What is the general RAM usage by Enterprise applications, developed on Xamarin?

Please note that all these RAM usage statistics are collected using the Android Studio Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce Xamarin android application memory usage, do followings:

1- Use liker (Link All is better) to reduce loaded assemblies into memory.

2- Use AOT/LLVM to remove JIT overhead including memory usage.